# react - Fetched Mapview Markers not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble with mapview markers that I'm fetching from a json file. I can have custom markers if I import it from a file but I need to import the coordinates from json. I am getting my current location from setState in componentDidMount without problems but it seems like it doesn't work the same way with Markers. I am testing around with logging and it seems the first two rounds in the render the array is empty but since I am setting initialRegion at the same place I don't understand the problem?
Here's (some) of my componentDidMount:

```
return fetch('https://url.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        data : responseJson,
      });
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
  });
```

and here's part of my MapView:

```
<MapView style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
            latitude:this.state.latitude,
            longitude:this.state.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.043,
            longitudeDelta: 0.034
                }}


                ref={c => this.mapView = c} 
                onPress={this.onMapPress}
                loadingEnabled={true}
            >

        {this.state.data.map(marker => (
          <MapView.Marker
          key={marker.name}
          coordinate={{
          latitude: marker.lat,
          longitude: marker.lng,
        }}
        image={img}
        title={marker.title}
        description={marker.description}
        />
        ))}
```

Comment: Can you make a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) example?

Comment: Okay, I'll try that!